# Any way to consume POST requests via browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications, polling, alerts

Say you've got an app that can send out POST requests every time an action happens. It allows subscriptions to add/drop quickly and effortlessly.

Say that site is Stackoverflow and it can send a you POST notification every time a new question is asked. Would there be any way to consume notifications like this in browser?

I imagine a case when you spend > 5 min on a page you start to get notifications if it's updated since your last page refresh. I understand how you could do this via long polling but I am wondering if there's any way to hook into these server-to-client POST requests (vs. repeated GET client-to-server requests) from a browser and let data be pushed to you instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For pushing you could take a look at HTML5 [WebSocket API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/).

Answer (score 1):

How about a lightweight web server on the client like [Jetty?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29)

Comment: Thanks for this. Will look into it now!